# Integration test with seed data or programmatically generated objects?

Tags: unit-testing

We're having a bit of a discussion in the office about how to implement good integration tests.

Example:
Account Creation
1. Create User
2. Add Role

One case we test is, if there is already a user with the same email address.
For this, I first created a user (programmatically ) and then tried to create an account with the same email.

Now the argument was, that I should be just seed our DB with this existing user and ONLY try to create an account (not have the first CreateUser in the test). Since like this I also implicitly test the "CreateUser" part and it adds functionality to the test that is not necessary, which could lead the test to fail for the wrong reasons.

My point was that it's easier to create the user programmatically and that the CreateUser function is already tested elsewhere. And this way you have all data contained in this one test case, so it's easier to understand.

What do you guys think about this?

Comment: Might be important to note that if your test accesses a database, it is not a unit test.

Comment: What Vincent said.  That's an integration test, not a unit test.

Comment: Fair enough. But at some point I have to check if the data goes into the database correctly and that we can retrieve it correctly. But anyway, that is a bit outside of the scope of this question.

Comment: Ok, changed the question.

Comment: At some point, you guys that are testing your databases in unit/integration tests have to start trusting your database to do the right thing.  Mocking a database is fine, but all it really tells you is that you're making the call correctly, and if you make an error coding the test, it will tell you the wrong thing.  If I had a preference, I would include the database in the test; at least that would be a *real* test.

Comment: Personally I prefer to have some fixtures with basic data which get loaded before each test. That way your tests become much simpler. Let's say you don't have any data, what do you do when you test a user-list? First createUser() with all steps involved and finally checking whether that user is on the list? If you have 2 users in your fixtures you can just test users-list.count() === 2. If you want to be sure a new users is added to the list just add one users and test users-list.count() === 3. Much less duplicated code in your tests.